# Php echo url inside an echo

Tags: php, url, echo

I am aware that I cannot use an echo inside an echo. My php code is:

```
echo '<img src="img/image1.jpg"
```

I want to use php variable as the source. Somethink like:

```
echo '<img src="php-code"
```

Comment: `echo "<img src='$src'...`

Comment: Do try to learn basic php before asking on SO.

Comment: @Epodax Be a bit supportive. He is obviously in the very basics of scripting and it could be tough to formulate Google queries and find correct place to look for such a thing.

Comment: @JosefSábl There are PLENTY of tutorials / guides / step-by-steps out there, in more than one language, SO is not a place where you learn the basics, you come here if you have a issue with specific code. - If you hover over the down vote button you'd literally see a "Shows no research effort"

Comment: Although you should learn the basics, how about `echo "<img src='{$url}'>"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .(dot) you can concatenate php variable in echo statement.

```
echo '<img src="'.$src.'" />';
```

Comment: Why concatenation is required in this case??

Comment: Because you use `single quotes`, variables between `single quotes` are not interpreted as such

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You have four options:

```
$url = '...';

//1
echo '<img src="' . $url . '">';

//2
echo "<img src='{$url}'>";        //Note that you have to use double quotes

//3
echo '<img src="';
echo $url;
echo '">';

//4
echo '<img src="', $url, '">';    //I would not recommend this one though
```

Answer (score 0):

just skip first echo and write the html with an echo in the middle

```
<img src="<?=$src?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these works

```
echo '<img src="', $url, '">'; # This works by sending 3 different parameters to echo
echo '<img src="' . $url . '">'; # This works by concatenating 3 strings before echoing

echo '<img src="'; echo $url; echo '">'; # This works by echoing 3 strings in turn

echo "<img src=\"$url\">";   # All of these works by inserting
echo "<img src=\"${url}\">"; # the value of $url in the string
echo "<img src=\"{$url}\">"; # before echoing. " needs to be escaped.

# And finally, this (called HEREDOC) does the same thing as above
# only without ", so that sign is not needed to be escaped
echo <<<FOO
    <img src="$url">
    <img src="{$url}">
    <img src="${url}">
FOO;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.
I prefer this one: `<?php echo '<img src="'.$url.'">'; ?>`
$url stands for the Image-Url, I guess you know ist.

You can do it also:
For example: `<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>">`
But I like the first method, it's a simple way to put out strings.